# Access object size from field calculator in print layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am creating a print layout in QGIS. I created a rectangle and I would like to fill it with a line pattern, in such a way that there are exactly five repetitions of the pattern through its height. However, QGIS enables me to choose the spacing, not the number of repetitions, so I would like to use the field calculator to specify `height_of_this_rectangle / 4` as spacing.

The problem is that I don't understand how to access the height of the rectangle as a variable in the field calculator expression.

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the height of the rectangle using the following expression:

```
bounds_height( $geometry)
```

This will calculate the maximum height of the bounding box of your geometry

[image]

Comment: I cannot use `$geometry` in print layout mode. It evaluates to NULL, so that `bounds_height` cannot extract anything useful from it. Does `$geometry` work for you in print layout mode?

Comment: Is the rectangle that you are considering to use a geometry contained in a layer or a simple shape created in the layout?

Comment: It is a rectangle shape created in the print layout manager, so the second one that you say.